# Calculated column - All records from [today] and [today]+5 when comparing to Due Date

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to create a view where Invoice Admin wants to see all the records where invoice due dates are within next 5 days. I added a calculated column and i have =[DueDate]-5 but this formula only gives me the records that have a DueDate 5 days from now. Is there a way to get all the records that are due from today to 5 days from today?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a calculated column for this. Just use your existing [DueDate] column twice in your view filter:

Show the items when column
`DueDate`
is greater than or equal to
`[Today]`

and

when column
`DueDate`
is less than or equal to
`[Today]+5`

Comment: The list is huge.

Comment: Did you perhaps set the filter to *or* instead of *and*?

Comment: And you can **not** do it with a Calculated Column, because the Formula is only updated when a List Item is changed. So you have to do it with the filter in a View as Dan Henderson explains.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view with filter where due date is less than `[Today] - 5`